# CakePHP 3 Not Saving Associations?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

ok, so my will give me the following `$this->request->data` output,

```
'editions' => [
    'title' => 'edtionTest',
    'active' => '0',
    'timestamp' => (int) 1438342639
    'articles' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'picinfo_id' => '1',
            'image' => '/img/test222.jpeg',
            'title' => 'test222',
            'maintxt' => 'Donec diam tortor, ullamcorper non,....'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'picinfo_id' => '2',
            'image' => '/img/TEST-NEW.jpeg',
            'title' => 'TESTING_AGAIN',
            'maintxt' => 'Donec diam tortor, ullamcorper non......'
        ]
    ],
]
```

Then I try to get the table and save,

```
$GetTable = TableRegistry::get('Editions');
$NewED = $GetTable->newEntities($this->request->data(),['associated' => ['Articles']]);

debug( $GetTable->save($NewED) );
```

And my debug, returns the following error,

```
Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::save() must implement interface Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, array given,
```

I don't think this has anything to do with my model(s). I have followed the documents, as far as I can tell to the letter but not sure what I am doing wrong?

---

### Edit

If I do this,

```
 $NewED = $GetTable->newEntity($this->request->data);
```

I get a return false, however when I do this,

```
 $NewEd = $GetTable->newEntity($this->request->data['editions']);
```

That works fine, it saves but it only seems to save the editions data and nothing to do with the associated articles.

All Help most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not sure if this is the best way, but I went though the docs again and re-read everything.

It works only when you loop though the inputs,

```
$NewEds = $GetTable->newEntities($this->request->data());

foreach ($NewEds as $NewKey => $NewValues) {
   $GetTable->save($NewValues);
}
```

It also seems that if you have 'join' tables done, it seems you don't have to have the `associated`